# Possible mistake in Apostol calculus: integration of the logarithm function

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms

The exercise set 6.9 of calculus I Apostol lists the following to find the antiderivative:

$$a) \int \log^2(x)\;dx$$

The solution in the back of the book is:

$$b)\; x\log^2|x| - 2x\log|x| + 2x + C$$

I think that the answer should be the same, except all $\log|x| \rightarrow \log(x)$. By definition, we have $\log(x)$ and not $\log|x|$. It means that the logarithm $\log(x)$ under integration cannot accept any negative term. Hence, its antiderivative should not accept it either, because the derivative of (b) is $\log^2|x|$, which is clearly different to me than $\log^2(x)$. Is it a mistake in Apostol, or I do not understand something about the domains here?

Comment: Real logarithm is defined only for $x>0$, so $|x|=x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, at this stage in the book - we have only real logarithms. So, it is a mistake in Apostol solutions? What made me suspicious - there are around 5 more similar questions - all result in absolute values in the logarithms, which I also think should be defined only for $x>0$, and instead have $\log |x|$ in the solution sheet.

Comment: I think J.W Tanner's point is that $\log x$ and $\log |x|$ are the same thing.  You can't have an error if what is written is the same thing as the right thing.  $x\log^2|x| - 2x\log|x| + 2x + C = x\log^2 x - 2x \log x + 2x + C$

Comment: "the derivative of (b) is $log^2|x|$, which is clearly different to me than $log^2(x)$".  Well, that's your problem.  Because $x > 0$ they should be clearly exactly the same to you.

Comment: @fleablood, I take your point, but I think OP also has a point. Consider the question, evaluate $\int_{-2}^{-1}\log^2(x)\,dx$. The correct answer is, the question is nonsensical, since $\log x$ is only defined for positive $x$. But someone relying on the antiderivative given in the back of the book would get an answer, of necessity an incorrect answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thx for the nice example! Exactly summarises my confusion - $\log(x)$ and $\log|x|$ have different domains, so cannot be used as substitutes for one another. Since the 2nd theorem does not give the same result ^ as you show (badly specified integral), it is a clear indication the Apostol solution manual is wrong. There are 5-6 similar exercise answers there, and solution manuals all across internet also copy Apostol's answer without even explaining how they get $\log|x|$ from $\log(x)$! Probably they do it to conform to Apostol's manual, which is disturbing... :(